# in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given error

Tags: mysql

I have a form that displays a checkbox for each engineer in a table.  When the form is submitted if the engineer's checkbox isn't ticked they are removed from the job ($diary_id).

The code as it is at the moment works but a page briefly displays this error before going back to the next page.

in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given error

The code on the form...

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE type = 'engineer' ORDER BY first_name";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>

      <div style="width:70px; float:left">
      <input type="hidden" name="engineer_on_page[]" value="<? echo $row['id'];  ?>"/>
          <input type="checkbox" name="engineer[]" <?
          $eng_id= $row['id'];

              $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calls_engineers WHERE call_ce = '$diary_id' AND engineer_ce = '$eng_id'");
              if((mysql_num_rows($result2)) > 0)
              { echo 'checked="checked"';
             ?> value="<? echo $row['id']; ?>" />
          <? echo '   '.$row['first_name']; }
             else {
                 echo "value=".$row['id']." />";
          echo '   '.$row['first_name'];
             } 
              ?>
      </div>

  <? } ?>
```

The mysql to remove the unselected engineers

```
foreach($_POST['engineer_on_page'] as $engineer_id) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM calls_engineers WHERE call_ce = '$diary_id' AND engineer_ce = '$engineer_id'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
                if(!in_array($engineer_id, $_POST['engineer'])){
                    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                        $sql = "DELETE FROM calls_engineers WHERE engineer_ce = '$engineer_id' AND call_ce = '$diary_id'";
                        $result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
                    }           
                }

            }
```

I have tried to initialise $_POST['engineer'] as an array ($_POST['engineer'] = array();) before the foreach loop which stops the error, but it also stops the page working, no error messages, it just doesn't work any more.

I am aware that the page needs to be updated to mysqli but I would like to resolve this issue before I do.

Thanks

Comment: replace `if(!in_array($engineer_id, $_POST['engineer'])){` with `if(isset($_POST['engineer']) && is_array($_POST['engineer']) && !in_array($engineer_id, $_POST['engineer'])){`

Comment: @Ejay, thanks for that but it stops the page from working

Comment: `stops the page from working` you mean you get some error? or it doesn't execute the delete statement?

Comment: no error, it just doesn't delete the engineer from the job

Comment: you should post your complete **generated** HTML for the `<form>` that's making POST request to the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only 1 engineer is checked, the value might be a string, not an array.

Then, I would add an `is_array()` before calling the `in_array()`:

```
if(is_array($_POST['engineer']) && !in_array($engineer_id, $_POST['engineer'])){
    // code          
}
```

There are actually a lot of ways that you could structure that, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Hi, If I add that it stops the page from working, the checked engineer does not get removed from the job

Comment: Before your foreach, try adding this: `$engineer = is_array($_POST['engineer']) ? $_POST['engineer'] : array($_POST['engineer']);` Then, in your original code, change the $_POST['engineer'] on that 4th line to the variable `$engineer`.  Or else, check your logic and SQL results.